# Shabuninil FileUp And Progress Bar (Var Event Not Defined)

Tags: jquery

I have the code working from [Source](https://shabuninil.github.io/fileup/) with the exception of the progress bar, and it boils down to "event" not being defined, when "onProgress" is called. While debugging, and checking event, it is defined, at other places, but when onProgess is called, event loses everything. Other calls also gives me the issue in console (all due to event):

```
onProgress fileup.js:51
callEvent fileup.js:156
onprogress fileup.js:605
```

Does not have a lot on the use and issues, or known bugs, must be not a lot of people use it, but is a nice project, and easy to use.

Anyone use it, or can explain why the "event" variable is not defined, or gets wiped out?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure yet, but i found the issue. For those that come across this post, on line 51 in the FileUp.js (non min), change "event" to "ProgressEvent", and the code will update the bar. and clear the rest of the call errors.

The code must have been forked, or maybe the non min js file did not get updated, have not look at the min.js file yet.